# If statement not seeming to check other && in statement

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have an if statement that looks as follows:

```
int count=0;
string Check;

if ((count==4 && Check!="-s")||(count==4 && Check!="-S"))
```

If `count` equals 4 and `Check` equals `"-s"` or `"-S"` it still enters this `if` statement because of the `count == 4`. It totally seems to ignore the second part. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: For compare strings in c++, you must use the `compare()` funcion like this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Comment: @Joan Lledó: The C++ `std::string` class overloads the `==` operator so that it "magically" works in this case.

Comment: Try: if(count==4 && Check!="-s" && Check!="-S")

Comment: You have the answer in your question: "if count equals 4 and Check equals -s or -S". This is how you should have written the if-statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if `Check` is `"-S"`, then it will not even check the second pair of conditions, because you check with `||`. The same holds true for the opposite case. If one is false, the other is true. Replace that with a `&&`.

```
int count = 4;
string Check = "-S";

if( (count == 4 && // count is 4, alright.
     Check != "-s") || // Check is "-S", alright I'm done thanks to || (OR)
    (count == 4 &&
     Check != "-S") )
{
  // ...
}

int count = 4;
string Check = "-s";

if( (count == 4 && // count is 4, alright.
     Check != "-s") || // Check is "-S", time to check the other condition pair...
    (count == 4 && // count is 4, alright.
     Check != "-S") ) // Check is "-s", which is different from "-S", perfect.
{
  // ...
}
```

Now the corrected version:

```
int count = 4;
string Check = "-S";

if( (count == 4 && // count is 4, alright.
     Check != "-s") && // Check is "-S", different from "-s", now on to the other condition!
    (count == 4 && // count is 4, alright.
     Check != "-S") ) // Check is "-S"... oh dang! No executed code for you.
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's always going to be the case that either `Check!="-s"` or `Check!="-S"`.  Hence, your if statement is equivalent to `if (count==4)`.

Answer (score 2):

If `count == 4` and `Check == "-s"`, then the expression to the right of the `||` is true. If `count == 4` and `Check == "-S"`, then the expression to the left of the `||` is true. So you have true or true which is true. Thus, your if-block is executed.

Answer (score 2):

The right statement is:

```
if(count==4 && (Check != "-s" || Check!="-S"))
```

The statement that you wrote is true if you have count = 4 and Check = "-S" because then the first part of the OR is true.

Comment: This also fails because the first part of the OR is true.

Comment: At least **one** part of the OR is always true.

Comment: Since @vrxacs used Check="-S" in his example, I meant that would cause the first part of the OR to be true.

Answer (score 2):

Might be more clear to use:

```
if (count==4 && Check!="-s" && Check!="-S")
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use !strcmp(Check, "-s") and !strcmp(Check, "-S") instead of !=.

If you use == you compare the pointers and that is no what you want. The pointers will always be different thus your second argument will always be true.

Comment: Uh, that's if you're dealing with char*, not with the type `string` which is part of <string> in c++ which has operator== overloaded

Answer (score 1):

You want to enter the if body if and only if Check is != from either -s or -S and count is = 4 right?

```
if ( (Check!="-s" && Check!="-S") && count==4 )
```

should work.

or

```
if ( Check.tolower() !="-s" && count==4 )
```

should work.

(Do not remember the name of the function to lowercase a string, you have got to look it up)

Hope this help.